# Can't get past "diagnosing PC" in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, boot, windows-8.1

I use my laptop rather intensely and a couple days ago my HDD started to sound weird. I got bluescreen and since then I can't boot windows, windows safe mode anything. There's a big text saying "diagnosing your pc" and if I wait ~1.5 hour (really), i got another menu. Linux runs fine, but it can't access files on the windows drive (same hdd, different partition).

Is there a way to fix windows or at least access the files?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a bad hard drive which might need replacement especially because of the weird sound you're hearing. In any case, theres a couple of programs that can confirm if you're hard drive is bad or not but you could start with a couple of stuff before you do that

1. a) use your windows 8.1 dvd and go in repair mode. Then do a chkdsk on you're windows drive (usually C...sometimes D. You'll have to check first)
   b) go watch a movie, its going to be long
2. then you could do some bootrec commands like the bootrec /fixmbr then bootrec /fixboot and bootrec /rebuildbcd
3. after all of this is done just reboot and it should be good. If not, then just post the error if its different

It may be a good idea to test you're hard drive so you could use hd tune (http://www.hdtune.com/) to know if its in good order or not.

Comment: what if I don't have a cd anymore? I got this PC for almost 3 years

Comment: Download the ISO from Microsoft

Comment: Go to the main login screen and click on the power button and hold the shift key on your keyboard and click on restart. You should get to the "troubleshooting option screen". From there you'll be able to get your command prompt and run the commands I told you in my answer

Comment: @LateGameReviewer Your suggested comment only works if they can get into Windows, but the author, is stuck in a boot loop